# Python 3, one class used across multiple modules

Tags: class, function, python-3.x

I would like to use the following class across multiple modules without needing `log = InitLog()` in every module. I need to be able to use ONE defined class variable (in this example `log`) across multiple modules. What is the best way to do this without altering my current code too drastically. Thanks

```
import os
import sys
import pdb
import fileinput
import Tools


class InitLog:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def setLaws(self):
        self.sound = 'off'
        self.engine = 'goo.txt'

    def Update(self):
        while Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress == True: pass
        Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = True
        try: os.remove(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log')
        except: pass

        summery = 'sound: ' + self.sound + '\n'
        summery += 'engine: ' + self.engine + '\n'

        path = os.getcwd()
        if not os.path.exists(self.dest): os.makedirs(self.dest)
        if os.path.isfile(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log') == True: os.remove(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log')
        with open (path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
            a_file.write(summery)
        Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = False


Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = False
log = InitLog()
log.setLaws()
log.sound = 'on'
log.Update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module called `logging` which contains `log`.  In other modules use `from logging import log`.