# Python: use of one logger instance across multiple module

Tags: python, global-variables

As a newbie to python I finally managed to create my own customized logger in a class in an extra module (tools.py). One of the main achievements here is that I can set the name of the logger and with the name also the log file name.

I want to instantiate the logger in main in one module (recalc.py) and from here call a function prepData in another module (getData.py). That function prepData in module getData.py is supposed to use the logger instance I instantiated in recalc.py. prepData is calling other function in the same module that shall use the same logger instance.

I fail to get the grips on how do declare / instantiate the logger since only the in module recalc.py with the main function knows the correct name for the logger.

```
    module tools.py
    :
    class Logg():
        :
```

.

```
    module recalc.py
    import tools
    from getData import prepData
    :
    lg = Logg("recalc", ...)        # instantiate the logger
    :
    result = prepData(...)
```

.

```
    module getData.py
    :
    def otherFunc()
        lg.debug(...)
        :
        return X

    def prepData(...)
        lg.info(...)
        :
        x = otherFunc(...)
        :
        return RES
```

I read a lot about (not really existing) global variables in Python, also [Python 3, one class used across multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080862/python-3-one-class-used-across-multiple-modules) and others. The config.py solution implies to initiate the global variable in config.py itself. But that doesn't work for me as only the main module knows the logger name.

The workaround I have right now is not acceptable in the long run.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You can initiate a nameless logger on config.py and set a name for it in your recalc module.

Comment: that's an idea! I'd need a method in class Logg though as the log file needs killing & re-opening under new name then I guess.